# Segment trisection without compass

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to figure out how to trisect a segment using only pen and ruler.
There is a parallel line provided.

No measurement is allowed.

Comment: I think you need a compass too..!!

Comment: If we are given one fixed circle with its center included, we can do everything with just a straightedge.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%E2%80%93Steiner_theorem

Comment: Do you have a given line parallel to the segment?

Comment: @OscarLanzi yes i do i forgot about it.

Comment: What is a "metric oc."? Please describe the problem fully; there's no need to be terse here.

Comment: You do not need compasses, which is the point.  The parallel line indirectly provides the relative distance measurements you need.  See Kazz's own answer (which could have been included in the q as working).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lets mark ends of the segment as A and B.

- mark points C and D on the parallel line.
- draw lines BD and AC, mark the cross point as E
- draw lines BC and AD, mark the cross point as F
- draw line EF, mark its cross point with line CD as G
- draw line BG, mark its cross point with line AD as H

The line EH cuts segment AB in 2:1 ratio.

Comment: can this be done easier (faster) ?

Comment: Beat me to it, +1.

Comment: I know of no faster method without compasses.

Comment: What is the parallel line? Is it a line that happens to be parallel to AB some distance away?

Comment: yes, just as the name suggest :)